# System.IO.FileNotFoundException In ConfigurationBuilder Constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying add the ConfigurationBuilder in an .net core console application
I'm getting this exception when running the code below.
I checked and in the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` the file appsettings.json is present.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)
   at DashboardService.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

Comment: The exception is about missing assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.FireProviders.Physical`, not about the actual config file `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical to your project.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physical/
Here you can take it.
Hope it helps

Comment: If a nuget package was missing the code wouldn't compile to begin with.

Comment: For some reasons i was able to compile even without the library

Comment: And i figured out why. I was not using nuget packages but adding assemblies manually :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try doing something like this instead.

```
  configBuilder
        .AddYamlStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("/your/path/here")))
        .Build();
```